# Asymptotic Joint Distribution of Variance and Ratio of Mean and Standard Deviation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, asymptotics

I am working on an exercise from a textbook about asymptotic distributions and I happen to see the question and I am interested in knowing how to solve it.

The question is: If $X_i$ are i.i.d with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, assuming that $\mathrm{E}(X^4_1)<\infty$. I am interested in deriving the asymptotic distribution of $(S^2_n, \bar X_n/S_n)^\top$. $\bar X_n$ is the sample mean and $S^2_n$ sample variance.

Here's what I did so far: By the bivariate CLT, we have that
$\sqrt{n}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
S^2 \ \\ \overline{X}/S  \end{pmatrix} 
-
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu \\ \sigma^2  
\end{pmatrix}\right)\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} N(0, J_{g(a)} \Sigma J'_{g(a)}) $

If we let $g(u,v) = \begin{pmatrix}
v-u^2 \\ \frac{u}{\sqrt{v-u^2}}
\end{pmatrix} $ then we have
$$ 
J 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-2u & 1 \\ 
\frac{v}{(v-u)\sqrt{v-u^2}} & \frac{-u}{2(v-u^2)^{3/2}}
\end{pmatrix} 
\text{ so that } J_{g(a)}= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
\frac{1}{\sigma } & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ where } 
a = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\\sigma^2
\end{pmatrix},  \text{ and }   
\Sigma 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2  & \mu_3  \\ 
\mu_3 & \mu_4-\sigma^4
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Covariance Matrix:
$$J_{g(a)} \Sigma J'_{g(a)} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
\frac{1}{\sigma } & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2  & \mu_3  \\ 
\mu_3 & \mu_4-\sigma^4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
\frac{1}{\sigma } & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_4 - \sigma^4 & \frac{\mu_3}{\sigma} \\ 
\frac{\mu_3}{\sigma} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
S^2 \ \\ \overline{X}/S  
\end{pmatrix} 
\stackrel{\text{asym}}{\sim} 
N\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu \\ \sigma 
\end{bmatrix}; \ 
\frac{1}{n}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_4 - \sigma^4 & \frac{\mu_3}{\sigma} \\ 
\frac{\mu_3}{\sigma} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
$$